# How combine a variable and a string to form a new variable?

Tags: php

Is it possible to combine a variable and a string to a new variable and echo it?

I have the following string:

`$string = '01001'`

Trying something like:

`$var = $_$string`

Ultimately I want to end up with a var like `$_01001` that I can print. So if I have a bunch of data like:

`$_01001 = 'foo';
 $_01002 = 'bar';
 $_01003 = 'fooz';
 $_01004 = 'barz';`

So `echo $_01001;` would produce `foo` ... thanks in advance.

Comment: yes its possible with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), why in the world would you want to call those values that way anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use. have a look on below example:

```
$_01001 = 'foo';
$_01002 = 'bar';

$string1 = '01001';
$string2 = '01002';

echo ${"_$string1"};
echo ${"_$string2"};
```

Output: `foobar`

mode detail available at [Variable of variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question how can I get this to work in a loop ... seems to only set the first time around?

Comment: can you give some idea what your logic is? and how you want to use it in loop?

Comment: Err, I figured i out ... (had empty strings). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '01001';
$vals = [
    '01001' => 'foo',
    '01002' => 'bar',
    '01003' => 'fooz',
    '01004' => 'barz',
];
echo $vals[$string];   // produces "foo"
```

Yah, I know, boring and lacking magic.  But readable maintainable code is often boring and magicless.  Variable variables voodoo does exist in PHP but will just distract future readers/maintainers (including yourself 1+ weeks from now) from what you're really trying to do in your logic.